# How to add a character to specific lines using grep/awk/sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I want to search a file and add \1 to the end of every line that begins with @. One issue is grep doesn't like "\1". This is a few lines of how the file looks:

```
@SRR1248080.1 1 length=90
TCTCACTGGCTGACTGAAGGCATGTCTAGTATTCAGAGTTTGCTACGATTTGGTACCGCTTTCGCAGCCC
GCACCGAAACAGTGCTTTACCCCTAGACAGCTCATAGTCAACCGCTGCGCCTCAACGCATTTCGGGGAGA
ACCAGCTAGCTCCGAGTTCGATTGGTATTTCACCCCTAACCACAGCTCATCCGCTGATTTTTCAACATCA
@SRR1249238.1 1 length=173
GCACCGAAACAGTGCTTTACCCCTAGACAGCTCATAGTCAACCGCTGCGCCTCAACGCATTTCGGGGAGA
ACCAGCTAGCTCCGAGTTCGATTGGTATTTCACCCCTAACCACAGCTCATCCGCTGATTTTTCAACATCA
```

I'd like it to read:

```
@SRR1248080.1 1 length=90\1
TCTCACTGGCTGACTGAAGGCATGTCTAGTATTCAGAGTTTGCTACGATTTGGTACCGCTTTCGCAGCCC
GCACCGAAACAGTGCTTTACCCCTAGACAGCTCATAGTCAACCGCTGCGCCTCAACGCATTTCGGGGAGA
ACCAGCTAGCTCCGAGTTCGATTGGTATTTCACCCCTAACCACAGCTCATCCGCTGATTTTTCAACATCA
@SRR1249238.1 1 length=173\1
GCACCGAAACAGTGCTTTACCCCTAGACAGCTCATAGTCAACCGCTGCGCCTCAACGCATTTCGGGGAGA
ACCAGCTAGCTCCGAGTTCGATTGGTATTTCACCCCTAACCACAGCTCATCCGCTGATTTTTCAACATCA
```

Comment: `sed '/^@/s/$/\\1/' file` or `awk '/^@/{$0=$0"\\1"}1' file`

Comment: At least in sed, backslash one has a special meaning. It refers to the first "numbered save" or "register" or "back reference". If you don't define one, it won't know what to do. Try escaping the backslash with another backslash.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `\1` to the end of every line that begins with a `@` is bread & butter for `sed`.  You simply specify a regular expression matching the lines to modify, and you can use an `s` command to sub in your tail for the zero-length end of line:

```
sed '/^@/ s/$/\\1/' input_file
```

Note the doubling of the backslash to suppress its special meaning to `sed`.

You might want to skip subbing lines that have already been subbed, perhaps by a previous run.  That's not hard either: just match those lines and use an `n` command to output them without further processing:

```
sed '/\\1$/ n; /^@/ s/$/\\1/' input_file
```

Note that the `sed` script is enclosed in single quotes, not double quotes; it makes a difference (to the shell) here.

Comment: Worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@aeli: Try(if you are interested in awk solution) too:

```
awk '/^@/{print $0"\\1";next} 1'  Input_file
```

It is simple, look for a line which is getting started from @ if yes then print complete line along with "\1" and do next(means skip all other mentioned actions). Mentioning 1 means: in awk it works on condition then action method, so I am putting 1 here which is making condition TRUE here and mentioning no actin here so by default print of current line will happen.